# Erratic behavior of Vue.js application in test mode (rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rspec, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I have a Rails 6 application which I test with rspec, Capybara and Chrome headless on a remote VM. With the new webdrivers gem, not that ancient poltergeist thing.

It has an user manager mini-app written in Vue 2.something that behaves in some stupefying ways:

**Excerpt from Vue application**

```
{
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    initial_load_completed: false,
    users: []
  },
  created: function(){
    this.loadUsers();
  },
  methods: {
    loadUsers: function(){ /* straightforward JSON load from server into .users and set .initial_load_completed to true */ }
    /* lots of other code */
  },
  computed: {
    hasUsers: function(){
      return this.users.length > 0;
    }
    /* lots of other code */
  }
}
```

**View excerpt**

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- loads of other code -->
  <div v-if="!initial_load_completed && !hasUsers">Loading your users, please wait...</div>
  <div v-if="initial_load_completed && !hasUsers">There are no users for your account right now...</div>
  <!-- lots of other code -->
</div>
```

The application works perfectly in prod and dev, on chrome, safari, tablets, iphones, even on my 3 year old smart TV Trashroid, even on IE. But under rspec tests it does things such as this:

[image: Capybara capture]

This example with those 2 divs showing/hiding based on users loaded is just a small thing that's wrong in this picture, many other controls were supposed to not show with an empty users array. And this is a happy happy joy joy case, about 50% of example runs it just doesn't output anything at all, #app is blank... randomly.

In my test.log I see how the Vue app hits the JSON endpoint of my back-end and how it renders data with a 200.

For the life of me I can't imagine how `initial_load_completed` can be true and false at the same time.

What I've tried? 
Rebooted the machine (heh). Then reinstalled all software to latest versions.
Then spent about 2 days trying to get chrome to work on a "virtual" display to which I would connect to see what's going on... after some 218 iterations fixing various deps/errors and configurations and code and signs and more errors and so on I just gave up.

**Driver definition:**

```
Webdrivers.logger.level = :DEBUG
default_chrome_args = [ '--disable-extensions', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0' ]
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
   capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome( loggingPrefs: { browser: 'ALL' }, chromeOptions: {
       'args' => default_chrome_args + ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1920,1600' ]
   })
   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities
end
```

CSP's are disabled, tried with and without them anyway.

Yesterday I tried logging JS errors:

```
config.after(:each, type: [ :feature, :system ], js: true) do
    errors = page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
    if errors.present?
        aggregate_failures 'javascript errrors' do
            errors.each do |error|
                expect(error.level).not_to eq('SEVERE'), error.message
                next unless error.level == 'WARNING'
                STDERR.puts 'WARN: javascript warning'
                STDERR.puts error.message
            end
        end
    end
end
```

... no luck.

```
config.after(:each, type: [ :feature, :system ], js: true) do
    errors = page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
            errors.each do |error|
                STDERR.puts error.message
            end
end
```

... also nada just like several other few variations of this code.
Can't even seem to get the examples to "puts :whatever" to stdout but that's another story.

Can someone kind at heart pretty please help a poor dumb me not lose all hair?

Comment: Poltergeist is equivalent to a 9 year old browser - I'm amazed anything from a modern web app is rendering in it - time to upgrade.

Comment: Yeah I did some time ago

Comment: then what are you actually using - the statement "With the new webdrivers gem, that ancient poltergeist thing." in your question makes it unclear.  Also before attempting to get the JS logs did you enable them in your driver registration (assuming using selenium)?

Comment: Thomas am I supposed to do more in the driver definition than already done as per above?

Answer (score 0):

Something that is not clear from the code samples in your question, is whether you are actually applying the driver you are defining.

System tests will use the default driver, so you must set it explicitly:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) {
    driven_by :headless_chrome
  }
end
```

It can also be applied on a per-scenario basis on feature tests:

```rb
RSpec.feature 'Balance' do
  scenario 'check the balance', driver: :headless_chrome do
    ...
  end
end
```